# JavaScript Iterative Variable Filtering

Tags: javascript, memory-editing

Is there a tool that allows us to search for a javascript variable just like a memory editor does: through iterative filtering either by exact value or change?

(Sorry for the long intro, but it's the best way I found to describe my use case.)

When I was about 14 yrs old, I would use a memory editor to find, monitor, and edit variables in games.

This allowed me to understand a bit better how computers work but also allowed me to have fun, changing the variables of the games to whatever I liked (offline, of course ;) )

The program would show me all variables.
I would then reduce the list of variables by repeatedly filtering: either by searching for its exact value (if it was known) or by change (increase, decrease).

Now I find myself wanting to do the same for Javascript. I've searched for a while, and I've tried different things, including searching for the variables in the `window` variable in console (please keep in mind I'm not a javascript developer) or using the debug function (which works great if you know where the variable is) but I haven't found a similar solution.

Is it true that no tool exists like this?

There so many use-cases:

- debugging: finding where that number with that weird value is;
- fun: edit variables just for plain fun, in games, etc;
- learning how to code: I learned how to program by "hacking" around, and I know I'm not the only one ;)
- probably many others I can't think about.

Does anyone know anything like this?

Comment: **Chrome** **Dev Tools** has a **Memory** tab which allows you to create a heap snapshot. That snapshot will contain all variables and their values. [More details](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/heap-snapshots)

Comment: Also, be aware that many games and websites using modern frameworks will have a *lot* of bloat and indirection in their memory snapshots, plenty of which won't even be specific to the program, so finding variables is not a trivial task unlike on older memory limited platforms.